# How to shorten an extremely long list in HTML

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I need to shorten a very long list of manufactures for my website.  The code looks like this currently:

```
<div class="container">
   <section id="manufacturerIndex" class="page-layout no-breadcrumb pb80">
      <h1 class="page_headers">Shop By Brand</h1>
      <!--START: manufacturer-->
      <li id="mfg_[id]" class="mfg-name list-group-item"><a 
href="search_groups.asp?manf=[id]">[manufacturer]</a></li>
      <!--END: manufacturer-->
      <ul class="manufacturer-index list-group">
         <!--START: manufacturerindex-->[category structure goes here]
         <!--END: manufacturerindex-->
      </ul>
   </section>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things but nothing looks right.  Just want a simple drop scroll kind of thing. Even if I could just get the box to just show 8 or so and than scroll.  I am so doing something wrong.

Any ideas on what to throw in there?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example: `ul.manufacturer-index.list-group { max-height: 20em; overflow-y: scroll; }`?

Comment: Are you dynamically filling the list depending on  the manufacturer chosen? How long is the resulting list? Could it potentially be broken down into subheadings?

Comment: No, the list just comes in from the product data and is alpha order.  The list is about 100 long.  I've been trying to create a drop almost like a pick a state box.  I'm not very advanced in html. I might have to hire this out.

Answer (score 0):

Like David Thomas suggested in a comment on your post, the `overflow-y` CSS property is useful for your needs.

1. Read about [how `overflow-y` works on the MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y).
2. Here's a CodePen example (written in [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), an HTML templating language) that shows a possible solution to your question in action: https://codepen.io/bzelip/pen/rZbbZL.
3. And here is the above Pug code compiled to HTML for running here inside Stack Overflow (press the "Run code snippet" button below the code to see the solution in this page):

```css
.dropdown-container {
  max-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page_headers">Shop By Brand</h1>
<ul class="dropdown-container">
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_0"><a href="#">mfg_0</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_1"><a href="#">mfg_1</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_2"><a href="#">mfg_2</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_3"><a href="#">mfg_3</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_4"><a href="#">mfg_4</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_5"><a href="#">mfg_5</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_6"><a href="#">mfg_6</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_7"><a href="#">mfg_7</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_8"><a href="#">mfg_8</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_9"><a href="#">mfg_9</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_10"><a href="#">mfg_10</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_11"><a href="#">mfg_11</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_12"><a href="#">mfg_12</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_13"><a href="#">mfg_13</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_14"><a href="#">mfg_14</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_15"><a href="#">mfg_15</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_16"><a href="#">mfg_16</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_17"><a href="#">mfg_17</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_18"><a href="#">mfg_18</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_19"><a href="#">mfg_19</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_20"><a href="#">mfg_20</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_21"><a href="#">mfg_21</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_22"><a href="#">mfg_22</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_23"><a href="#">mfg_23</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_24"><a href="#">mfg_24</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_25"><a href="#">mfg_25</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_26"><a href="#">mfg_26</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_27"><a href="#">mfg_27</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_28"><a href="#">mfg_28</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_29"><a href="#">mfg_29</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_30"><a href="#">mfg_30</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_31"><a href="#">mfg_31</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_32"><a href="#">mfg_32</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_33"><a href="#">mfg_33</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_34"><a href="#">mfg_34</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_35"><a href="#">mfg_35</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_36"><a href="#">mfg_36</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_37"><a href="#">mfg_37</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_38"><a href="#">mfg_38</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_39"><a href="#">mfg_39</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_40"><a href="#">mfg_40</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_41"><a href="#">mfg_41</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_42"><a href="#">mfg_42</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_43"><a href="#">mfg_43</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_44"><a href="#">mfg_44</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_45"><a href="#">mfg_45</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_46"><a href="#">mfg_46</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_47"><a href="#">mfg_47</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_48"><a href="#">mfg_48</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_49"><a href="#">mfg_49</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_50"><a href="#">mfg_50</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_51"><a href="#">mfg_51</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_52"><a href="#">mfg_52</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_53"><a href="#">mfg_53</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_54"><a href="#">mfg_54</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_55"><a href="#">mfg_55</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_56"><a href="#">mfg_56</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_57"><a href="#">mfg_57</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_58"><a href="#">mfg_58</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_59"><a href="#">mfg_59</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_60"><a href="#">mfg_60</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_61"><a href="#">mfg_61</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_62"><a href="#">mfg_62</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_63"><a href="#">mfg_63</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_64"><a href="#">mfg_64</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_65"><a href="#">mfg_65</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_66"><a href="#">mfg_66</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_67"><a href="#">mfg_67</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_68"><a href="#">mfg_68</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_69"><a href="#">mfg_69</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_70"><a href="#">mfg_70</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_71"><a href="#">mfg_71</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_72"><a href="#">mfg_72</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_73"><a href="#">mfg_73</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_74"><a href="#">mfg_74</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_75"><a href="#">mfg_75</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_76"><a href="#">mfg_76</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_77"><a href="#">mfg_77</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_78"><a href="#">mfg_78</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_79"><a href="#">mfg_79</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_80"><a href="#">mfg_80</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_81"><a href="#">mfg_81</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_82"><a href="#">mfg_82</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_83"><a href="#">mfg_83</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_84"><a href="#">mfg_84</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_85"><a href="#">mfg_85</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_86"><a href="#">mfg_86</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_87"><a href="#">mfg_87</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_88"><a href="#">mfg_88</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_89"><a href="#">mfg_89</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_90"><a href="#">mfg_90</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_91"><a href="#">mfg_91</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_92"><a href="#">mfg_92</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_93"><a href="#">mfg_93</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_94"><a href="#">mfg_94</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_95"><a href="#">mfg_95</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_96"><a href="#">mfg_96</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_97"><a href="#">mfg_97</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_98"><a href="#">mfg_98</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_99"><a href="#">mfg_99</a></li>
  <li class="mfg-name list-group-item" id="mfg_100"><a href="#">mfg_100</a></li>
</ul>
```

Good luck!